# Android's Backup Manager to backup a minimal file

Tags: java, android, file, key, backup

is it possible to use 
Android's Backup Manager
to backup a minimal file
(A text file with 20 words?)
I can't quite understand if this is possible and how to do it. ..

Answer (score 0):

As you can read at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html you can save any type of data, including files.

Also take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/backup/FileBackupHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the original backup APIs, you probably just want your BackupAgent implementation to extend android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper, and then use a FileBackupHelper configured for the file you want to keep backed up.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/FileHelperExampleAgent.java is an example of using FileBackupHelper for a single file.  There are other example agents in that same sample code directory that show other alternatives for keeping data backed up.

On Android 6.0 (Marshmallow) and later, there is a new file-based backup API you can use instead that requires much less code in your application, possibly none at all.  Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html for an overview of how you can use this new facility to get automatic backup of a file without having to actually write your own backup agent.